# Apagar options dentro de optgroup

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `select` com dois `optgroup`. Quero em JS apagar todas as `options` que estão só num dos `optgroup`.

```
<select id = "testSelect" name="testSelect">
   <optgroup label="opt1">
      <option value="3">Apples</option>
      <option value="1">Oranges</option>
      <option value="2">Pears</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="opt2">
      <option value="4">ford</option>
      <option value="6">toyota</option>
      <option value="5">ferrari</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Neste exemplo quero apagar as `options` do `optgroup` 2. Algo deste genero:

```
$$("input[type=select][id=^testSelect][label="opt2"]").each(function(curr){
//get outgroup
//remove all options;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim para apagar tudo (inclusive o `optgroup`)

```js
document.querySelector('optgroup[label="opt2"]').remove();
```

```html
<select name="testSelect">
   <optgroup label="opt1">
      <option value="3">Apples</option>
      <option value="1">Oranges</option>
      <option value="2">Pears</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="opt2">
      <option value="4">ford</option>
      <option value="6">toyota</option>
      <option value="5">ferrari</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Ou usar isso para deletar somente os `options`

```
document.querySelectorAll('optgroup[label="opt2"] option').forEach(function(el) {
    el.remove();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado funciona. E depois de apagar adicionar uma nova option nessa opt2?

Comment: @akm Ai já é uma outra pergunta, crie uma nova pergunta com a sua dúvida e me manda o link por aqui para te ajudar.

OBS.: Se a resposta funcionou para sua pergunta inicial marque ela como solução para que outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida que você possam ser ajudadas também.